# Counter inside of scala for comprehension

Tags: scala

I have this piece of code.

```
for {
   country <- getCountryList
   city <- getCityListForCountry(country)
   person <- getPersonListForCity(person)
}  {...}
```

When we run this code, we need to have a counter inside the body of the loop which increments every time the loop executes. This counter needs to show the number of people processed per country. So it has to reset itself to 0 every time we start executing the loop for a new country.

I tried

```
for {
   country <- getCountryList
   counterPerCountry = 0
   city <- getCityListForCountry(country)
   person <- getPersonListForCity(city)
}  {counterPerCountry = counterPerCountry + 1; ...}
```

but this says that I am trying to reassign a value to val.

so I tried

```
var counterPerCountry = 0
for {
   country <- getCountryList
   counterPerCountry = 0
   city <- getCityListForCountry(country)
   person <- getPersonListForCity(city)
}  {counterPerCountry = counterPerCountry + 1; ...}
```

also tried

```
for {
   country <- getCountryList
   var counterPerCountry = 0
   city <- getCityListForCountry(country)
   person <- getPersonListForCity(city)
}  {counterPerCountry = counterPerCountry + 1; ...}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the counter in the loop? Could you not do something like `counter <- 1 to getList1.length`?

Comment: OK. think of list1 as country. list2 as city and list 3 as person. The counter needs to count the number of people that were processed per country. So each time we pick a new country (from list1) we need to reset the counter. The counter has to increment everytime the loop iterates because we show the status of processing using the counter.

Comment: Ok, so does the counter need to go from 1 to list1.length? If so, I think my comment above provides the desired syntax...

Comment: On second thought, testing in the REPL proves me wrong... you need a counter that keeps track of what position within list1 a is though right?

Comment: New idea: use `a <- 0 to list1.length-1` and then a is the counter. To get the specific element in list1, use `list1(a)`. Does that work?

Comment: no because list1(a) will give you the name of the current country being processed.

Comment: "has to increment everytime the loop iterates because we show the status of processing using the counter" -> it means that the counter is read outside the context of the loop? By another thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @pamu that a for-comprehension does not seem the like a natural choice here.  But if you turn the for comprehension into the underlying operations, I think you can get a solution that, while not as readable as a for comprehension, works with Scala's functional style and avoids mutable variables.  I'm thinking of something along this line:

```
getCountryList flatMap (country => 
  (getCityListForCountry(country) flatMap (city => 
     getPersonListForCity(city))
  ).zipWithIndex
)
```

That should yield a list of (person, index) tuples where the index starts at zero for each country.

The inner part could be turned back into a for comprehension, but I'm not sure whether that would improve readability.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just trying to figure out how to assign a value to a `var` within a for-comprehension for science, here's a solution:

```
var counter = 0
for {
  a <- getList1
  _ = {counter = 0}
  b <- getList2(a)
  c <- getList3(b)
} {
  counter = counter + 1
  ...
}
```

If you're actually trying to count the number of people in a country, and you say it's the number of people in a city times the number of cities in a country - then it comes down to simple arithmetics:

```
for {
  country <- getCountryList
  cities = getCityListForCountry(country)
  city <- cities
  persons = getPersonListForCity(person)
  personsPerCountry = cities.length * persons.length
  person <- persons
}  {...}
```

Comment: so is there a non-dirty solution possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think for-comprehension allows this naturally. You have to do it bit hacky way. Here is one way to do it.

```
var counter = 0

for {
   country <- getCountryList.map { elem => counter = 0; elem }
   city <- getCityForCountry(country)
   person <- getPersonForCity(person)
}  {
  counter + 1
  //do something else here
}
```

or use function for being modular

```
var counter = 0

def reset(): Unit = counter = 0

for {
   country <- getCountryList
   _ = reset()
   city <- getCityForCountry(country)
   person <- getPersonForCity(person)
}  {
  counter + 1
  //do something else here
}
```

## People per country

```
val peoplePerCountry = 
 for {
   country <- getCountryList
   cities = getCityForCountry(country)
   city <- cities
   persons = getPersonForCity(person)
 } yield (country -> (cities.length * persons.length))
```

The code returns list of country, persons per that country

The above for-comprehension is the answer, you do not have to go for counter approach. This functional and clean. No mutable state.

Answer (score 1):

One more approach, if your only need is the actual sum would be something compact and functional such as:

```
getCountryList.map( country => //-- for each country
  (country, //-- return country, and ...
    getCityListForCountry(country).map ( city => //-- the sum across cities
      getPersonListForCity(city).length //-- of the number of people in that city
    ).sum
  )
)
```

which is a list of tuples of countries with the number of people in each country. I like to think of `map` as the "default" loop where I would have used a `for` in the past. I've found the index value is very seldom needed. The index value is available with the `zipWithIndex` method as mentioned in another answer.